# Excel - Treat Greater Than or Less Than Symbol as part of Text Criteria

Tags: excel

I have the following table data in MS Excel:

```
Doctor                  Patient Age Group
Doctor_Name 1            > 12 yrs old
Doctor_Name 2            < 06 yrs old
Doctor_Name 3            > 12 yrs old
```

When the formula =COUNTIF(B2:B4,"> 12 yrs old") is executed using this data, it will return 3 when in fact it should only return 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know where it is documented, but the function is interpreting the **>** (greater than) character as an operator and not as part of the string.  Try:

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$8,"=" &"> 12 yrs old")
```

If an operator is the first character(s) in the text string, it will be interpreted as an operator and not as a character.

Comment: Thank you for this.  This indeed the answer I need